# How do I get a Twig Variable I set from my twig extension?

Tags: symfony, twig

So.. I've been trying for awhile to get twig variables in my extension.

First I tried getting from `$environment->getGlobals()`.. But that was just that, indeed, just globals.  Then I tried referencing different parts inside of `getCompiler()`, no juice, many thing I tried instead just locked up my browser or php instance.

So what am I trying to do?

In my twig template I'm doing this

```
{% set myvariable = "something" %}
```

In my twig extension when I call a specific function I want to see if this variable was set something, if it was set something I want to perform a specific action.

Comment: Why don't you just call your extension function with this variable (or without, if not set)?

Comment: As @apfelbox says why can't you just pass the variable into the function?

Comment: I can yes.. But this variable isn't always set.. So I'd like to provide some logic on the twig side to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to the context from where your extension is called then you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: The context only gets you the variables that are set from the controller, it won't get you the variables set inside of the twig template

Comment: It should, how would the variables assigned in the template be passed along to the include tag.

Comment: They're inside twig nodes, its kind of cryptic how to get access to them.  Trust me, you can't get it with the context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Twig's Global Variables for Templates](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables)? I was looking for something similar (a mechanism to get *all* variables set in the context of a template) and stumbled across the `_context` global variable which held everything that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass twig variables to your twig extension by passing the global variable `_context` to your function. `_context` is an array which holds all variables from your template.

```
{{ my_twig_function(_context) }}
```